# Unable to cast object of type error during IIS Deploy -> Import Application

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Keep getting a

Unable to case object of type 
"Microsoft.Web.Development.DeploymentChangeSummary" to type
"Microsoft.Web.Development.DeploymentChangeSummary"

error when deploying a web app via IIS manager import application feature. It doesn't happen all the time either.

The server has Web Deploy 2.0 installed and have deployment delegation setup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem (used Web Deploy 2.0)
I changed to Web Deploy 3.5 and it's working now
(I uninstalled Web Deploy 2.0 via Control Panel before and used the Web Platform Installer in IIS to install the newer version on server 2012 -simply search for web deploy there)